# Laravel 5.4 Eloquent not returning object, it returned as array

Tags: php, database, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to get data from a model using eloquent queries. Instead of returning me an object it returns me an array. Code is shown below.

```
    public function showConversation($id,$cid){
    $conversation=conversation::where('from',$id)->orWhere('to',$id)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get()->all();
    $message=message::where('conversation_id',$cid)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();        
    $key='conversation';
    dd($message->id);
    return view('inbox')->with('conversation',$conversation)->with('message',$message)->with('key',$key);
}
```

By this in dd $message is not accessible as $message->id, it shows error is trying to get property of non-object. But when we use $message[0]->id, it is accessible. We want object of it. Can someone help?

Comment: Rename $message to $messages in your controller to use the plural form. A foreach in the view like `foreach ($messages as $message)`  should work unless something screwy is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Your retrieving the data as an array. If you would like to just receive a single message as a result, you should try the following code:

`public function showConversation($id,$cid){
    $conversation=conversation::where('from',$id)->orWhere('to',$id)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get()->all();
    $message=message::where('conversation_id',$cid)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->first();

    $key='conversation';
    dd($message->id);
    return view('inbox')->with('conversation',$conversation)->with('message',$message)->with('key',$key);
}`

In short:
Use `->first()` not `->get()`

Comment: we want to get all messages

Comment: how can we get an object with all messages into an object?

Comment: Then it's no wonder that it's an array? You are retrieving multiple messages, so it's returned as an array of Eloquent objects. The objects are contained in the array. I don't think it's possible to retrieve the data in an object.

Comment: how can we use that array in view in a foreach loop to do this like message->messagetext.

Comment: You are probably using blade templates so it would be something like the following:
`@foreach ($messages as $message)
    <p>This is the message body: {{ $message->messagetext}}</p>
@endforeach`

Hope this helps. Comments on StackOverfllow don't indent code very nicely :P.

Comment: we did tried that code already but it says trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Could you please check the output of:

foreach($message as $m) {
    var_dump($m);
    echo "<br />";
}
In your showConversation() function.
If this shows arrays, something is wrong, and my assumption is incorrect. Otherwise something weird is going on.